# Language Services in Intellij IDEA maxing out CPU

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, eslint

I have a fairly large project at my current work (about 3k ts and coffeescript files), and have started getting an issue using Intellij IDEA maxing out CPU and heap out of memory error.

Detailed here:

[image]

I also start then to see reports being output by Intellij .

```
 {
   3   │   "header": {
   4   │     "reportVersion": 1,
   5   │     "event": "Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory",
   6   │     "trigger": "FatalError",
   7   │     "filename": "report.20210511.141656.48623.0.001.json",
   8   │     "dumpEventTime": "2021-05-11T14:16:56Z",
   9   │     "dumpEventTimeStamp": "1620706616440",
  10   │     "processId": 48623,
  11   │     "cwd": "/Users/me/workspace/qwilr",
  12   │     "commandLine": [
  13   │       "/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/bin/node",
  14   │       "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/jsLanguageServicesImpl/js-language-service.js",
  15   │       "-id=1620706559593",
  16   │       "-debug-name=eslint"
  17   │     ],
           .....
```

Versions of eslint related issues:

```
   "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.23.0",
   "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.23.0",
   "eslint": "^7.26.0",
   "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.12.0",
   "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
   "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.4",
   "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
```

Also, this seems to have started since switching from npm to yarn.

Intellij details:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-211.7142.45, built on April 30, 2021
Licensed to XXXXXXX
Subscription is active until June 29, 2021.
Runtime version: 11.0.10+9-b1341.41 x86_64
VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.3.1
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 3987M
Cores: 16
Registry: debugger.watches.in.variables=false, ide.tooltip.initialDelay=592, ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: IdeaVIM (0.66), com.github.leomillon.uuidgenerator (4.3.2), com.mallowigi (36.0), com.mnr.java.intellij.idea.plugin.base64helper (2.0.3), AWSCloudFormation (211.6693.108), com.intellij.kubernetes (211.7142.13), intellij.prettierJS (211.7142.13), deno (211.6693.108), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.5.0-release-759-IJ6693.72), zielu.gittoolbox (203.5.8), org.intellij.scala (2021.1.18), com.jetbrains.php (211.7142.45), com.chrisrm.idea.MaterialThemeUI (6.4.1), com.jetbrains.twig (211.6693.44), Pythonid (211.7142.45), aws.toolkit (1.26-211), com.github.shiraji.yaemoji (1.0.7), ru.adelf.idea.dotenv (2021.1), ru.meanmail.plugin.requirements (2021.4-211)
Kotlin: 211-1.5.0-release-759-IJ6693.72
```

Comment: Same problem here, but I think it's better asked directly in Intellij support boards

Comment: (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003579280-IntelliJ-node-processes-using-a-lot-of-CPU-on-TypeScript-project-IntelliJ-performance-suffers- for example)